# dynamic field with linqToEntity (c#)

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

my code :

```
        public List<tblBook> GetBook(string NameField, string Value)
        {
            return (this.Entities.Book.Where(
            "it.@p0 NOT LIKE @p1",

new ObjectParameter("p0", string.Format("%{0}%", NameField)),

new ObjectParameter("p1", string.Format("%{0}%", Value)))).ToList();

        }
```

error :

> The query syntax is not valid. Near term '@p0', line 6, column 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields must be static. You cannot use wild cards in a field name. This `Where` extensions only builds Entity SQL query internally. Entity SQL follows the same rules as common SQL.

Edit:

Correct code is:

```
public List<tblBook> GetBook(string NameField, string Value)
{
    return this.Entities.Book.Where(
               String.Format("it.{0} NOT LIKE @p0", NameField),
               new ObjectParameter("p0", string.Format("%{0}%", Value))).ToList();
    }
}
```

You must pass whole field's name and you must validate it - Entity SQL injections exists as well.

Comment: No you must explicitly define what field you want to compare and if you want to compare more then one field you must use correct logical operator among these conditions. Your current approach is not valid query at all.